How to configure Prettier and ESLint to format TypeScript/JavaScript imports into multiple lines?
I'm working on a TypeScript project and I want to configure Prettier and ESLint to automatically format my import statements when the line width exceeds the predefined printWidth rule of prettier. Specifically, I want to split long import statements into two lines, like so:
Current Format:
import { 
 x,
 y, 
 z, 
 n, 
 h 
} from '@example/package';

Desired Format:
import { x, y, z } from '@example/package';
import { n, h } from '@example/package';

My current configurations:
Prettier Configuration (prettierrc):
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 120
}


ESLint Configuration (.eslintrc.json):
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "next/typescript", "eslint:recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn",
    "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
  }
}


I’ve tried using import/order from eslint-plugin-import and configured prettier-plugin-import-sort, but it seems like they don't achieve the desired import splitting.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to set this up correctly in a TypeScript project?
Additional Information:

I'm using Visual Studio Code and would like the formatting to happen on save.
I've ensured that both Prettier and ESLint are installed and working correctly, but they don't format the imports as expected.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I think, you'll have to implement the rule by yourself, which will include implementing the fix suggestion for the linter

Disable prettier and eslint via comments and write them like that manually.

To clarify, you are starting with import { x, y, z, n, h } from '@example/package';  and want to go to the 2-line version when that line exceeds printWidth`?

@Mark, yes, but not two lines within one import, I want them to become two import statements

Use eslint`s import/order and import/newline-after-import rules.
Example:
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "next/typescript",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["import"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn",
    "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off",
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "groups": [["builtin", "external", "internal"]],
        "newlines-between": "always"
      }
    ],
    "import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 1 }],
    "import/max-dependencies": ["warn", { "max": 10, "ignoreTypeImports": true }]
  }
}


please provide a full solution, I copy/pasted your code into an .eslintrc file, and formatting the code is no longer working again. Have you tried this solution?

You should also mention what's written in the .prettierrc as well
